# Need to send email using background worker process

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, smtp, backgroundworker

I have code written for sending email in C#, but the application hangs up when the application is sending mails size of attachments more than 2 MB. I was advised to use background worker process for the same by SO users.

I have gone thru the background worker process example from MSDN and google it also, but i don't know how to integrate in my code.

Please guide me in that...

thanks

**UPDATED: Email-Code Added**

```
public static void SendMail(string fromAddress, string[] toAddress, string[] ccAddress, string[] bccAddress, string subject, string messageBody, bool isBodyHtml, ArrayList attachments, string host, string username, string pwd, string port)
{
  Int32 TimeoutValue = 0;
  Int32 FileAttachmentLength = 0;
  {
    try
    {
      if (isBodyHtml && !htmlTaxExpression.IsMatch(messageBody))
        isBodyHtml = false;
      // Create the mail message
      MailMessage objMailMsg;
      objMailMsg = new MailMessage();
      if (toAddress != null) {
        foreach (string toAddr in toAddress)
          objMailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toAddr));
      }
      if (ccAddress != null) {
        foreach (string ccAddr in ccAddress)
          objMailMsg.CC.Add(new MailAddress(ccAddr));
      }
      if (bccAddress != null) {
        foreach (string bccAddr in bccAddress)
          objMailMsg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bccAddr));
      }
      if (fromAddress != null && fromAddress.Trim().Length > 0) {
        //if (fromAddress != null && fromName.trim().length > 0)
        //    objMailMsg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress, fromName);
        //else
        objMailMsg.From = new MailAddress(fromAddress);
      }
      objMailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
      objMailMsg.Subject = subject;
      objMailMsg.Body = messageBody;
      objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
      if (attachments != null) {
        foreach (string fileName in attachments) {
          if (fileName.Trim().Length > 0 && File.Exists(fileName)) {
             Attachment objAttachment = new Attachment(fileName);
             FileAttachmentLength=Convert.ToInt32(objAttachment.ContentStream.Length);
             if (FileAttachmentLength >= 2097152) {
               TimeoutValue = 900000;
             } else {
                TimeoutValue = 300000;
             }
             objMailMsg.Attachments.Add(objAttachment);
             //objMailMsg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileName)); 
           }
        }
      }
      //prepare to send mail via SMTP transport
      SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new SmtpClient();
      if (objSMTPClient.Credentials != null) { } else {
        objSMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd);
        objSMTPClient.Host = host;
        objSMTPClient.Port = Int16.Parse(port);
        //objSMTPClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        objSMTPClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
        //objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = true;
        //objSMTPClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
      }
      //objSMTPClient.Host = stmpservername;
      //objSMTPClient.Credentials
      //System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup mMailsettings = null;
      //string mailHost = mMailsettings.Smtp.Network.Host;
      try {
        objSMTPClient.Timeout = TimeoutValue;
        objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
        //objSMTPClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
        objMailMsg.Dispose();
      }
      catch (SmtpException smtpEx) {
        if (smtpEx.Message.Contains("secure connection")) {
           objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = true;
           objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       AppError objError = new AppError(AppErrorType.ERR_SENDING_MAIL, null, null, new AppSession(), ex);
       objError.PostError();
       throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't modify the code here as it is common method that is called whenever mail is to be sent from my application.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could provide your current code. We could convert it to background, rather than us providing with an example that you may not understand how to fit into your code.

Comment: @Fun Mun Pieng: I have added the code..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could start a background thread to continuously loop and send email:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    this.Controls.Add(bw);
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private bool quit = false;
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (!quit)
    {
        // Code to send email here
    }
}
```

Alternative way to do it:

```
private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
    client.SendCompleted += new System.Net.Mail.SendCompletedEventHandler(client_SendCompleted);
    client.SendAsync("from@here.com", "to@there.com", "subject", "body", null);
}

void client_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
        MessageBox.Show("Successful");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.ToString());
}
```

---

Specific to your example, you should replace the following:

```
try
{
    objSMTPClient.Timeout = TimeoutValue;
    objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
    //objSMTPClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
    objMailMsg.Dispose();
}
catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
{
    if (smtpEx.Message.Contains("secure connection"))
    {
        objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = true;
        objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
    }
}
```

with the following:

```
objSMTPClient.Timeout = TimeoutValue;
objSMTPClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
objSMTPClient.SendAsync(objMailMsg, objSMTPClient);
```

and further down, include:

```
void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
        MessageBox.Show("Successful");
    else if (e.Error is SmtpException)
    {
        if ((e.Error as SmtpException).Message.Contains("secure connection"))
        {
            (e.UserState as SmtpClient).EnableSsl = true;
            (e.UserState as SmtpClient).SendAsync(objMailMsg, e.UserState);
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.ToString());
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Error.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for inputs.So this code doesn't need to include any background process?
Also i am not getting AsyncCompletedEventArgs in intellisense.What could be reason for that?

Comment: add `using System.ComponentModel;` or change it to `System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs`

Comment: thanks for input again. last comment worked!
But the emails are not being sent. don't know why..

Comment: @Xor power, I'm not sure whether you should dispose your message. I haven't check whether SendAsync actually makes a copy of the message or uses your copy. If it uses your copy and you call dispose, I suppose an exception will be thrown after some time and the mail will fail. If it makes a copy, then there will be no problem. Please try it out to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great example of how to do this with a "Service Broker" in Chapter 8 of Richard Kiessig's book "Ultra-Fast ASP.NET."

Here's the link to the book on the publisher's website where you can download the sample code from the book.  Again, chapter 8...

http://apress.com/book/view/9781430223832

Comment: The advantages of using Service Broker to send email are that the requests are persisted, so they survive past an AppPool restart, and the tasks can be moved to a separate server if needed, for security and/or scalability reasons.